# OAuthException: Failed to generate request token with Salesforce

Tags: python, oauth, salesforce

I'm facing an issue I can't seems to fix, despite having tried everything I could.

I'm using Flask + Flask_oauthlib to connect to SalesForce. Here's my code :

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
oauth = OAuth(app)


salesforce = oauth.remote_app('salesforce',
    consumer_key='my_consumer_key',
    # grant_type='authorization_code',
    consumer_secret='my_consumer_secret',
    request_token_url='https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
    access_token_url='https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
    authorize_url='https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    url = url_for('oauth', _external=True)
    salesforce.authorize(callback=url)
    return 'ok'


@app.route('/oauth')
def oauth():
    resp = salesforce.authorized_response()
    print resp

    return 'ok'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

When I run this and goes to `/`, I get the following exception :

> OAuthException: Failed to generate request token

I added an output from the line in question where the exception is thrown ("/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask_oauthlib/client.py", line 580), and this is the response from Salesforce :

```
{u'error_description': u'grant type not supported', u'error': u'unsupported_grant_type'}
```

So apparently I need to set the `grant_type` to something allowed.

I tried to add the grant_type as you can see in the commented section, but when I restart the code, it stops with the following error :

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'grant_type'

Yay ...

I took a look, and applied the answers from the following questions, without any luck :

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34928/oauth2-token-request-using-json-fails-grant-type-not-supported
- [Salesforce returning "unsupported_grant_type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372774/salesforce-returning-unsupported-grant-type)
- [Salesforce Authentication Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794302/salesforce-authentication-failing/29112224)

Does anyone has an idea about why I have this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found the solution, it's really vicious !

```
salesforce = oauth.remote_app('salesforce',
    consumer_key='my_consumer_key',
    consumer_secret='my_consumer_secret',
    access_token_url='https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
    authorize_url='https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize')
```

Don't see the difference ? I had to remove the `request_token_url`, that's all !

Now it works!