# Where to get client_id and client_secret of Salesforce API for Rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

I've been following a tutorial from: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Accessing_Salesforce_Data_From_Ruby

But, I'm stuck with the part where you need to supply the keys:

```
host: login.salesforce.com        # Use test.salesforce.com for sandbox
client_secret: 1234567890         # This is the Consumer Secret from Salesforce
client_id: somebigidthinghere     # This is the Consumer Key from Salesforce
sobject_module: SFDC_Models       # See below for details on using modules
debugging: true                   # Can be useful while developing
username: me@mycompany.com
password: mypasswordplusmysecuritytoken
```

Where can I get the `client_secret` and `client_id`. The tutorial from the official API site of Salesforce is kind of outdated. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm

And some other tutorials didn't even mention where to exactly get it.

I already created an account in http://developer.force.com/

And even created a custom app, correct me if I'm wrong.

Then don't know where to find the keys that I need.

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Comment: See my detailed post about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794302/salesforce-authentication-failing/29112224

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you log in to developer.force.com, In the left nav

```
Build -> 
  Create ->
    Apps
```

The bottom of that page has "Connected Apps".  Click "New" to add the app you created.  You'll set your callback URL, description etc.  Once you hit save you'll see your consumer id and secret.

Comment: Thanks to you. Saved me a lot.

Comment: If you've already created it, click 'edit'. On the next page, click 'save'. You'll be back at the same page as described by the answer here.

Comment: The structure of the site has changed slightly since this questions was answered, see my answer below if you're having any trouble accessing the screen referred to here

Answer (score 8):

The structure of the salesforce admin panel has changed slightly since this question was answered. Here is how you now access the screen referred to in the answer by trh:

[image]

Comment: How would you then get to the client id/secret from this screen?

Comment: Very late to this party, but to answer @JacobHacker in case others get to this page: you would click the Connected App Name link (NOT "Edit" or "Manage"). So in the example you would click "Website". That takes you to a screen with the Key & Secret present.