# Using OAuth Token to Access Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am working on salesforce client integration. I want to get access token and i am using

```
URL : https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

Method : Post

Header : Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password

```
client_id=XXXXXXXXXX

client_secret=XXXXXXXXXX

username=XXXXXXXXXX

password=XXXXXXXXXX
```

Above credential working fine with grant_type=authorization_code but while i switched to grant type password then its gives me

```
"http/1.1 400 bad request"
{"error":"invalid_client_id","error_description":"client identifier invalid"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Salesforce Authentication Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794302/salesforce-authentication-failing)

Answer (score 1):

That looks right.  Try this with curl:

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  -d "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID" \
  -d "client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET" \
  -d "username=YOUR_USERNAME" \
  -d "password=YOUR_PASSWORD"
```

Comment: thanks for respoding, resolved my issue actually problem was my ip not white listed hence it gives me authentication error. and also i didnt mention my security token in body.