# Sales force authentication not happening in java script

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I got a sample from github , In that sample when we click a link it will be redirected to the salesforce login page.but when i click login after giving login credentials it's not authenticating . I am getting 401 error . Even i referred this link [Salesforce Authentication Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794302/salesforce-authentication-failing)
Not getting solution for my problem . i have tried like this

```js
  openLogin: function () {
   
       var clientId = "xxx";

       var consumerSecret = "xxx";

       //Authorization endpoint
       var authEndPoint = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize";

       //response_type must be set to token

       var responseType = "xxx";

       //This is the callback URL from the connected app

       var redirectURI = "xxxx";
       var username="xxxx";
       var password="xxx";
       username=encodeURI(username);
       password=encodeURI(password);

      var requestURL = authEndPoint+'?response_type=code&grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&response_type='+responseType+'&redirect_uri='+redirectURI+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;
       var res = encodeURI(requestURL);

       $window.open(requestURL);


    }
```

But when new window is opening the requested page doesn't appear .

Please help me if you know the solution .

Comment: "https://login.salesforce.com/services/" -->URL doesnt exist.Check this.

Comment: yes i need the help of exact url to make my application run .